# Are there notations for sum over permutations?

Tags: summation, permutations, notation

I am constructing combinatorial objects that have cyclic symmetry. I cannot remember if there is already a convention to indicate this. For example, if I have the sum

s = a<sub>1</sub>b<sub>2</sub>b<sub>3</sub> + a<sub>2</sub>b<sub>3</sub>b<sub>1</sub> + a<sub>3</sub>b<sub>1</sub>b<sub>2</sub>,

I want to be able to indicate the summation over permutations of terms of order 3. I could try building something out of Σ and Π but it would be nice to have something neater. I can't remember if I learned this before.

Comment: Wouldn't something like this (in this specific case) suffice?: $$\sum\limits_{σ\in\left < (1 2 3)\right > } a_{σ(1)}b_{σ(2)}b_{σ(3)}$$

Answer (score 1):

We can write this expression using *[cyclic sum](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Cyclic_sum)* notation
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}}a_1b_2b_3}&=a_1b_2b_3+a_2b_3b_1+a_3b_1b_2\\
\end{align*}
replacing the variables $a_1,b_2,b_3$ systematically in a cyclic manner.